# A Dark Room - What to do about the angry woman

Tags: a-dark-room

The woman in the Village seems very angry that I found the spaceship, and that I keep venturing out. My village is also Raucous, how do I fix this?

Comment: Kill her! Quash the rebellion before it can begin!

Comment: How do I kill her?

Comment: I was actually kidding about that part. I've never encountered her in any of my playthroughs. A raucous village is fine, it just signifies the maximum capacity of villagers that you can have.

Comment: Okay, also how do I get the Ship to work? I have it, but the controls don't do anything

Comment: You need to repair it with alien alloy first. You can also find any other information you need on the wiki at: http://www.adarkroom.wikia.com

Comment: I've never encountered and angry woman, and searching the github depo doesn't give any results for 'woman', 'girl', 'angry', or 'mad'. Looking through the code I couldn't find anything like this. Maybe it was removed? Can you give more information about what tab/screen you were on, or text from what the event said?

Comment: I think @HelpME is referring to "she". She's the one who accuses the player of being a murderer, blood on your hands, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The text 'Raucous Village' is not actually a status ailment or bad in any way; it is simply a description of the *size* of your village. When you build enough huts to reach the  maximum size of 80 villagers the text will change to read 'Raucous Village'. This is normal.